# What is <Object> in void init(Handle<Object> exports)

Tags: c++

I am looking at the node.js documentation for making a module. http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

I understand template functions and template classes such as

```
template <class T>
void MyTemplateFunction(T a) 
{
    a.doSomething();
}

...

MyObj mo;
MyTemplateFunction <MyObj>(mo);
```

This code looks a little but like a template but I have never it before:

```
void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
    // what is <Object>?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Handle<Object>` is a specification of a [*template class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29#Class_templates) (as opposed to a [*template function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29#Function_templates), which you show above). There is a declaration of

```
template <class T>
class Handle {
    ...
};
```

somewhere in your code or in one of the header files that you included. Essentially, `Handle<Object>` is a class produced using a `Handle` template by replacing `T` with `Object` throughout the template's code.

Comment: i thought it looked like a template. okay, thank you for explaining that to me.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, `Handle` is a class template with a single type parameter:

```
template <typename T> class Handle;
```

and presumably `Object` is a type.

This instantiates the `Handle` class template, using `Object` as the template argument, to give a class; just as your example instantiates the `MyTemplateFunction` function template, using `MyObj` as the template argument, to give a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same thing:
`exports` is declared to be of type `Handle<Object>`, with `Handle` being a class template taking one (most likely) type argument. It's probably declared similar to the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Handle{...};
```